# UIImageView and UILabel display issues in a UITableViewCell using Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm having issues displaying some image views and text labels using a custom `UITableViewCell`.

This is what is happening:

[image]

A shot of the storyboard:

[image]

Some of the issues is that the `UILabel` text does not get replace and it's ghosting. Also, for the 2nd row, there should only be 2 `UIImageViews` but there's 3, because there's text for the middle that shouldn't have been shown.

AboutCustomCell.swift:

```
class AboutCustomCell: UITableViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet var threePicRow_leftImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var threePicRow_leftNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var threePicRow_leftPositionLabel: UILabel!

    ...

    @IBOutlet var twoPicRow_leftImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var twoPicRow_leftNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var twoPicRow_leftPositionLabel: UILabel!

    ...
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell3Pic = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("3PictureRowCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AboutCustomCell
    let cell2Pic = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("2PictureRowCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AboutCustomCell

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell3Pic.threePicRow_leftNameLabel.text = "Name"
            cell3Pic.threePicRow_leftPositionLabel.text = "Position"
            cell3Pic.threePicRow_leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_about")

            cell3Pic.threePicRow_middleNameLabel.text = "Name"
            cell3Pic.threePicRow_middlePositionLabel.text = "Position"
            cell3Pic.threePicRow_middleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_about")

            cell3Pic.threePicRow_rightNameLabel.text = "Name"
            cell3Pic.threePicRow_rightPositionLabel.text = "Position"
            cell3Pic.threePicRow_rightImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_about")

            return cell3Pic
        case 1:
            cell2Pic.twoPicRow_leftNameLabel.text = "Name"
            cell2Pic.twoPicRow_leftPositionLabel.text = "Position"
            cell2Pic.twoPicRow_leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_about")

            cell2Pic.twoPicRow_rightNameLabel.text = "Name"
            cell2Pic.twoPicRow_rightPositionLabel.text = "Position"
            cell2Pic.twoPicRow_rightImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_about")

            return cell2Pic
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Will never reach here
    return cell3Pic
}
```

Is there something I'm not doing to the custom cell that would cause this? Thank you.

Comment: Do not dequeue cells you won't actually use. Move the dequeue inside the switch.

Comment: Do the prototype cells have the cell class AboutCustomCell?

Comment: @phlipsy: yes they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your options:

1. Most close to your own design, make sure you **hide and show** the images and labels that should not be shown **explicitly** in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, by setting their `hidden` property.
2. Better: create two different cell classes, one with 2 and one with three items per row. Dequeue only the cells you need and return those in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
3. Best: think about exploring UICollectionView instead.

Comment: To the first option: Do not forget to show needed elements. Simple hiding the unused ones brings you into trouble if your cells start getting reused.

Comment: @phlipsy Wrong. Setting the `hidden` property as indicated in my answer hides and shows the views as needed.

Comment: What do you mean with "wrong"? I think it's important to stress the fact that table cells get reused and manipulating them always bears a certain risk showing unwanted artifacts if not properly undone the next time.

Comment: I thought your comment was misleading because the problem you are raising is already addressed in my answer. In fact, I even emphasized this point with bold letters. I am afraid your comment is really quite inapplicable to the proposed solution. Sorry I used the word "wrong" which is strictly speaking not true. It should have been more like "redundant and potentially confusing".

Comment: @Mundi: with Swift 2.0, why is it that I still need to add `aboutTableView.dataSource = self` and `aboutTableView.dataSource = self` to conform to the protocols/delegates?...If I leave those code out in `viewDidLoad`, the table view is blank,

Comment: That is an entirely different issue. You have shown a screenshot that displays the cells, which implies that you have already set delegate and datasource. You can ask a new SOF question if you want more clarity on this (after accepting the above answer).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I can't reproduce this behavior since I don't have any Apple hardware right here.

But I suspect the problem comes from the fact that table cells are reused or that always some outlets aren't properly connected but get nevertheless instantiated.

Three possible solutions:

**The minimal/dirty one:** Set the text of the unused outlet labels to the empty strings.

**The elaborate one:** Define two different cell classes for the two and three picture rows.

**The completely different one:** If you actually don't have dynamic content inside your table view don't use a table view, instead use a hand taylored layout.

Comment: It's just a wild guess.

Comment: Well, I set up 2 different cell classes, and still the same results.

Comment: Do these cell classes define only those outlets the corresponding prototype cell contains? Did you move the dequeues into the corresponding switch cases?

Comment: Yes to the first question. For the 2nd question, if I move the dequeues in the switch cases, how would I define a cell to return "outside" the switch statement since changes in Swift does not allow return of nil like in obj-C?

Comment: @Pangu you can simply add `return UITableViewCell()` at the end.

Comment: Please give at least a reason for downvoting.